# WSDL parsing causes outboudn internet connection to w3.org on weblogic12

Tags: java, wsdl, ejb, weblogic, weblogic12c

the problem:

We are having 2 .war files, both providing a set of webservices (JDK8, EJB), so both contain a WSDL file.
At deployment weblogic (12c R2) parses the WSDL files. Both contain a reference to w3.org(xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"). For one of the WSDL files this does not causes an outbound connection to w3.org, but for the other it does, and since the server is not allowed to have an internet access for security reasons, this causes the deployment to fail.

I tried to compare web.xml, weblogic.xml, weblogic-application.xml and the two WSDL files, but I do not see any difference that could cause the different behavior. (The two .war files are deployed on the same server).

Does anybody has a suggestion how to solve this?

Thanks in advance,

Ben.

Comment: could you add the wsdl's header to check those XSD URL's ?

Comment: this is the one that does not cause any problems:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<wsdl:definitions 
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
    xmlns:xslt="http://xml.apache.org/xslt" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
    targetNamespace="..."

Comment: and this is the problematic:

 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions targetNamespace="..." 
    name="..." 
    xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
    xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" 
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" 
    xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
    xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I can't see much difference on those headers, anyway, the common workaround (when there is no internet connection) is to download the required XSD's to your project (war/jar) and reference them from WSDL without an URL, for instance:

from:

```
xsd="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
```

to:

```
xsd="oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
```

Comment: I tried it and I get the following error:

The document is not a schema@http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema: document element namespace mismatch expected "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" got "XMLSchema.dtd".

I tried it with ./ and .\ before the filename (the file is next to the WSDL), and I also tried XMLSchema.xsd, but always the same error.

What could be wrong?

Comment: a referenced XSD belonging to the SWDL had to be adjusted too, now it is working, thanks for the help